# C# Couldn't process file xxx.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file

Tags: c#, api, visual-studio-2012

I have an issue while I try to build project in VS2012.

It cannot build due to the error:

```
Couldn't process file xxx.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted 
zone or having the mark of the web on the file. Remove the mark of the web if 
you want to process these files.
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348919/couldnt-process-file-resx-due-to-its-being-in-the-internet-or-restricted-zone-o) is a similar question.

but I tried that option and had no luck, because I did not download the file from the internet. That project was built from scratch. In project after selecting Properties, in Windows Explorer nothing happened. I do not have the "unblock" option, only the default three options (read only, hidden, and archived).

I have the same error and cannot build or rebuild the project. I have a theory that it is a recent error after updating Windows. Before the update, everything worked fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couldn't process file resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348919/couldnt-process-file-resx-due-to-its-being-in-the-internet-or-restricted-zone-o)

Comment: What is the path to the resx file?

Comment: it's not duplicate. I tried that option with no luck, still have error.

File is located in local network hdd (UI\xxx.resx). But in project i have issue only with 2 files

Comment: For addition. I try this project on other computer and it built successfully. So I have hard time to find out, what chunk of Windows .net 4.5 getting blocking it after update.

Comment: I have clue. probably VS after update add Visual Studio Remote Code Execution Vulnerability (https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2018-8172). But, I don't have any file from web. I create own .png files to project, just that. Maybe someone know, how get rid of that problem ?

Comment: Ok, tell me one thing. I have this project on Qnap. I tried copy it on lical hard drive and everything rebuild well.
​So what i can do, to work on my local network version of project.

Answer (score 80):

Go to `xxx.resx` file in Windows File Explorer. Right-click and select properties. At the bottom of the the dialog is an "unblock" option:

[image: Unblock option]

Check this and click Apply. Clean your solution and it will build.

Comment: Great answer. I really needed that little spur of confidence too. Indeed, it is ok.

Comment: Is there a way to do this to more than one file at a time?

Comment: Does not work on Windows 10, I don't see an "unblock" check box

Comment: ruffin and @SQLPolice, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54568777/1220437 above with the PowerShell solution.

Comment: @SQLPolice , this option appears only if the file is blocked.

Comment: I have 70 files with same issue. I don't have this option "Unblock" on my files. What can I do? Can I simply say to VS I dont care?

Answer (score 28):

In my case I had the same problem with many files.

My solution with VS Prof. 2017 V15.95 was:

1. Open powershell and execute `dir -Path [directory path] -Recurse | Unblock-File`
2. Rebuild all

Comment: Doing just nothing

Answer (score 24):

1. On the solution folders locate abc.resx.
2. Open the file using any text editor, preferably Notepad++.
3. Locate and delete any node starting with `<data`

Example. This is what you should delete.

```
<data name="$this.Icon" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
     <value>
        AAABAAMAICAAAAEAIACoEAAANgAAAGBgAAABACAAqJQAAN4QAACAgAAAAQAgACgIAQCGpQAAKAAAACAA
        AABAAAAAAQAgAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
         ///////////8AAB///////// 
     </value> 
 </data>
```

4. Reload or reopen your solution and build. You are ready to go.

Comment: This is the ONLY solution that worked for me, and I tried *many* others: Powershell Unblock-File, "unblock" from properties (which was not present for me), totally recreating the file from scratch in a separate folder, then copying it into my solution folder, adding "file://[machinename] to intranet trusted sites, and others. NONE worked. I do not well understand "the mark of the web", but clearly, it was this CONTENT of my .resx file (the icon data) that was causing the problem, rather than any sort of meta data. I deleted this data and rebuilt with success.

Comment: The only way for me in VS2019 was to delete all the "System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing" data. Thanks.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 with VS 2019 and this is the only solution that worked for me as well.  Thanks much!

Comment: any node starting with what? with " ?

Comment: Delete the node which starts with "<data name="$this.Icon"" and you are good to go

Answer (score 13):

Had the same problem after updating to VS 2017 v15.8.5, and none of the solutions above or on other forums worked for me.

So, since a .resx file is just XML, I just copied the content, deleted the original file and recreated it with the copied content.

That was the only thing that worked, and it worked first time.

Comment: Same issue on VS 2022. What is the problem?

Answer (score 7):

A quick way to remove this mark of the web for multiple files and folders recursively for me was to

1. Zip them up.
2. Delete originals.
3. Unzip.

Comment: This actually worked for me.  I had downloaded the project from a cloud source and got this error despite all the files being local.

Comment: Ah the easiest is sometimes the best, thx Ditto.. I tried some of the tips here, but in W10, Powershell or reload I could not solve the issue. This did the trick.. propably there is more than 1 file "marked", zippin and unzipping the entire directory will apply the change to all files ?

Comment: This answer led me to an even easier solution: Unblock the original .zip file (or installer or whatever archive) *before* you unzip it. Then all the files that spill out of it won't be marked.

Comment: on Windows 10 I had no option to Unblock, all files were created locally(but stored on a NAS, trying to re-access after a fresh Windows install), tried powershell solution, tried to delete all <data> sections from the resx and NOTHING worked. Then I zipped and unzipped the whole project and put it back on the NAS. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure either, I have the exact same issue.

But, what i did, was hit view in file explorer.[image]

Then, i clicked show hidden items.
[image]

Finally, i went back to my folder and clicked on the .vs folder, my project/file name, v15, Server, sqlite3, and deleted DB.Lock.

[image]
I reopened the project, clicked build, and it worked perfectly.

This worked for me, it might/might not for you.

Comment: You could try to open process hacker and terminate anything you see that is out of place and/or is running after you close visual studio. I sometimes found that processes from VS were still running even after I did close the application...

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, VS2019 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution on another forum.  My project resided on a file share, so I had to enter file://[file share] for Step 4 below.  I am running VS2019 on Windows 10.

1. Start Menu > type 'Internet Options'.
2. Select Local intranet zone on the Security tab then click the Sites button
3. Click Advanced button
4. Enter file://[computer name] or file://[file share]
5. Make sure 'Require server verification...' is unticked

Comment: In my case, this was the solution!

Here's the specifics. I'm running Windows 10 for development in a VirtualBox VM. The host is Ubuntu. I have the git repo cloned on the Ubuntu file system, with it shared via Samba in order for VirtualBox to be able to access it via drive letter.

Comment: This seems to be the way to fix it if your solution lives on the nas rather than your local machine!

Comment: This fixed compiling for me, but I still can't run the EXE, btw my EXE requires admin access

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this issue recently. The error began occurring after I set the icon of a Windows Form.

Researching for the cause and solution almost led me nowhere, because I did not download the icon from the internet, nor was I referencing a web-based icon file. It was stored entirely on my local machine.

After some more researching and digging around, I was able to figure out exactly what was causing the problem. I have Microsoft One-Drive installed on my machine. The directory in which the icon file was located is managed/synced by One-Drive. That fact was somehow tricking Visual Studio into believing the file was located or downloaded from the internet.

The solution proved to be very simple. I removed the icon from the form, as well as from the corresponding .resx file. Then I moved the icon file to another directory not associated with One-Drive. Finally, I was able to use that icon in my Windows Forms application without getting this error.

I understand there are other possible causes for this error. But if in your case, the issue happened after setting a form's icon--and if you have One-Drive (or perhaps another cloud-based storage solution) installed--then check to be sure that icon file is not in a directory managed by that service. If so, relocate it and change the form's icon property to point to the new location.

Comment: Well okay, but I need the icon! I cannot just remove the icon.

Answer (score 2):

**To fix this for multiple files within a project**, Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Trust Settings and add the project path as a trusted path.

[image: Visual Studio trusted paths]

Answer (score 2):

Please guys, I already fixed the issue, this is cause by OneDrive, please close your OneDrive with the use of task manager or close the icon OneDrive's Hidden Icons on the taskbar

Comment: I suspect this was the common factor in my case, as the files didn't appear to have the 'Mark of the web'.  I hadn't checked OneDrive at the time, but a reboot solved the issue for me, and I could see then OneDrive was busy synching files.

Answer (score 2):

Using VS 2019, and building against source stored on an Azure shared file system.  I think I may have just tracked down a work-around, and it has to do with the Icon as referenced above by Jake above.  If I add the icon to the form's resource file (that really long string), The error occurs.

However, if I add the Icon to the Project's resources, delete the Icon from the form's resource file, and change form to set the Icon manually...

```
this.Icon = MyProjectName.Properties.Resources.MyIcon;
```

The error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Windows 10 VS 2019 16.4.457 (previous version of VS 2019 had no problems).

The "marked for web" error shows only after I moved the project under One-Drive.
If I move the project back to a local drive the error doesn't show.
As Anthony Gingrich suggested, I tried to move the project images to a local directory without success.

The solution that works for me was, for each image, in the "Select Resource dialog" use "Project resource file" instead "Local resouce".

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and also tried the Unblock option from explorer with no luck.  I even restarted VS with no luck.

However, I'm not sure which combination did the trick but I opened the form as well as the resx file from within VS, just to see if I can open it, which opened fine. I then did a clean and rebuild and that appeared to do the trick.  If it doesn't try restarting VS after the clean then rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the problem was an image that I had downloaded and added to my Resources. Not completely sure why that was the only image that gave me problems, however, I opened my abc.resx file giving me issues an a text editor, removed the node starting with " (it was the last and only node) just like Albert Alberto mentioned. Saved the changed, cleaned and rebuilt my solution and it all works! The image didn't render but it only took a second to go back and add the image. It wasn't removing the entire file, just the node that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on *Windows 10, VS 2017 (15.9.13)*. I sent myself a project from work through Dropbox so I could try a couple of things from home. But when I tried to build it VS gave me the 'marked for web' error.

After trying the solutions above without success I began experimenting. I was able to solve this by using the method listed above (right click -> properties -> unblock), but I had to *do it for each of the images in the Resource folder*--and I had to **do EACH FILE individually since the 'unblock' option was not available on group-selects**. I actually unblocked each source file in the project as well before trying to rebuild so I am not sure if both are required.

Its a bit of a pain--probably a huge pain for larger projects--but it absolutely got the project building again.

EDIT: I did find this article afterwards about unblocking entire folders--even recursively but have not tried it: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/bulk-unblock-files-downloaded-internet/

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me. I fixed it by converting the embedded base64 into a linked resource:

I found out the issue was with the embedded base64 image I had in the .resx (as the issue went away removing the data tag as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53095311/15001063) but that meant I removed the image) so I converted the embedded image into a .png file and made a link to that in the .resx.

To do that: open the .resx file in Visual Studio 2019 and double-click the image, and then click Ok and Yes in the following prompts that will appear so VS will convert the embedded image into a linked resource (sorry I can't upload pictures yet):

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps!

From [my original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71799430/15001063).