# Visual Studio 2017 - C# - Couldn't process (*.resx) file due to its being in the internet or restricted zone or havign the mark of the web

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, office365, onedrive, resx

I am getting the following Error message on Run (Build) -> 
"**Couldn't process file 123.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file. Remove the mark of the web if you want to process these files.**" 
There are 4 forms in the project and Visual Studio 2017 (VS2017) shows error for all the 4 related resx files in this C# project.

Here are the key points.

- I am running VS2017 Ent on a Win10x64 Ent sys, and everything (os, software including VS2017 and sys drivers) on this sys are updated as and when it becomes available.
- I have a 1TB OneDrive storage access through corporate Office365 Ent, and I use this cloud storage to store all my data. VS2017 project location is customized to be stored on this OneDrive.
- I didn't make any changes on this computer or VS2017 or even on this project, apart from **updating my OS**.

I have tried the following steps and it does not solve my problem.

1. "UNBLOCK" Solution as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348919/couldnt-process-file-resx-due-to-its-being-in-the-internet-or-restricted-zone-o). 
   *My .RESX files does not have this UNBLOCK option inside its Properties tab. (Windows Explorer).* 
   Furthermore, I have made sure that there are currently no resources (Images or Icons downloaded from the web that are being used in this project) that has any "Unblock" option on their Windows Explorer Property. (There were some with the "Unblock" options highlighted, that I promptly UNBLOCKED). 
   Interestingly, one of the forms in this project that gets this error, does not have any outside resources on it (plan form), so the theory of using items downloaded from the internet is nullified here.
2. Under Internet Options -> Security -> Local Intranet Zone -> Sites -> Advanced **=**

   - Entered "file://[my computer name]" into "Add this website to the zone:"-> and confirmed the same to be under "Websites:"
   - Confirmed that the checkbox option "Require server verification (bla bla bla)..." is unticked (not selected).
3. Deleting and Recreating the .resx file solution as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356602/c-sharp-couldnt-process-file-xxx-resx-due-to-its-being-in-the-internet-or-restr). 
   Backing up the .ResX files to a diff dir -> Deleting the same from the project dir -> Recreating it using notepad (copy/paste info from it's backup) -> Relaunching VS -> Recompiling = Did not fix my issue.

By the way, recently I observed that dragging and dropping (aka mouse copy paste) any files on the ONEDRIVE (source and destination both on the one-drive) throws the following error msg 
*"These files might be harmful to your computer. Your Internet security settings suggest that one or more files may be harmful. Do you want to use it anyway?"*.
 
Since I started seeing this message recently, I am wondering if this and the stuff happening in VS has something to do with the recent Windows Update, which had updates for the Office 2016 Pro Plus along with other updates.

Comment: add your `file server` to my Trusted Sites in Internet Options. Reloaded the project and it built normally after that

Comment: Which File Server to add in Trusted Sites? Does Onedrive has file server which needs to be added and if so then how do we do that?

Comment: New in the Creator's edition [by the looks of it](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-unblock-apps-download-files-stored-cloud-windows-10).

Comment: The "Allow" button on the Automatic file downloads option under my Privacy -> Settings are greyed out.

Answer (score 3):

a bit old question, but my solution is using Powershell:

```
 ps> Get-ChildItem -Path '<YOUR-SOLUTION-PATH>' -Recurse | Unblock-File
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I was able to solve my problem. I knew that the issue had something to do with the "one drive" cloud storage, but I was wrongly suspecting the issue had something to do with the Windows10 recent OS updates.

I realized today that I was not able to locate the work onedrive (1TB) to a physical location on the hard drive with the same title. So, on closer inspection, I realized that not only the work onedrive is missing from it's customized path (under custom user directory (D:\users\"MyUserName"), but also there is this new "Favorites" folder. Upon opening the folder, I was flooder to see it's contents same as my work onedrive folder. That's when the realization hit me, and I recollected a particular incident around the time, where I was amended the default Windows Favorites location to OneDrive (for better continuity and cross platform / device experience). 
Now I must have made a mistake in defining the path to Favorites, which would have resulted in the work onedrive being assigned as Favorites.
 
So, I made the following changes and that solves my problem.

1. Reverted Favorites location back to default (C:\users\"MyUserName"\Favorites). 
    Right click -> Property -> Location -> Making above changes -> Move -> Option **"Don't copy existing files to new location"**.
2. Renaming D:\users\"MyUserName"\**Favorites** -> **OneDrive"MyWorkName"**.

After the above changes, I can now compile the project from the "work onedrive" without any error messages.

Thus, if anyone is ever facing the same problem, and also if the UnBlock solution is not fixing the problem, make sure to check and confirm the path of all customized location, viz all Windows Library and One Drive.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the solutions listed here and in these:

- [C# Couldn't process file xxx.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356602/c-sharp-couldnt-process-file-xxx-resx-due-to-its-being-in-the-internet-or-restr/71827845#71827845)
- [OneDrive - Visual Studio 2019 - Couldn't process file Form1.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64929131/onedrive-visual-studio-2019-couldnt-process-file-form1-resx-due-to-its-bein/71799430#71799430)

And still couldn't get it working, I ended up converting the embedded image into a .png file and made a link to that in the .resx. Visual studio does it for you with just 2 clicks as I described in my original comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/71799430/15001063