# OneDrive - Visual Studio 2019 - Couldn't process file Form1.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone

Tags: visual-studio, onedrive

I created a new project with **Visual Studio 2019**, in Form1 I placed a ImageList component with one image.
The project builds fine.

When I copied the project from the local folder to any **OneDrive** folder I get the error:

> Couldn't process file Form1.resx due to its being in the Internet or
> Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file. Remove the
> mark of the web if you want to process these files.

If I delete the image from the imageList1 Images collection the project builds again.

I tried answers from similar questions with no luck:

1. The file Form1.resx it does not have the "Unblock" option
2. In Visual Studio / Tools / Options / Environment / Trust Settings, I added the OneDrive folder:
   C:\Users\[my user name]\OneDrive\Documents\OneDrive
3. In Visual Studio / Tools / Options / Environment / Web Browser / Internet Explorer Options...
   Security / Trusted sites / Sites, I added the websites: 
   file://[my computer name]
   https://onedrive.live.com

I have Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8.1, Windows 10 version 1909.
The project builds fine with Visual Studio 2013.
Any new ideas?

Comment: Because you say _"If I delete the image from the imageList1 Images collection the project builds again."_ then it sounds to me like the 'mark of the web' is on the image, and the resource file is inheriting it. So I would suggest checking the image's properties for 'Unblock', or using [PowerShell's `Unblock-File` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file)

Comment: @stuartd The image does not come from internet, I did it with Photoshop, and  it does not have the "Unblock" option. I have the same issue with any image.

Comment: So have you tried the Powershell option?

Comment: @stuartd I tried now with Form1.resx and with the image file, but it does not work. The docs say that Unblock-File command "Unblocks files that were downloaded from the Internet" but it is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it work doing something I couldn't find anywhere in StackOverflow.

I found out the issue was with the embedded base64 image I had in the .resx (as the issue went away removing the data tag as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53095311/15001063 bu that meant I removed the image) so I converted the embedded image into a .png file and made a link to that in the .resx.

To do that: open the .resx file in Visual Studio 2019 and double-click the image, and then click Ok and Yes in the following prompts that will appear so VS will convert the embedded image into a linked resource:

[image: - https://i.stack.imgur.com/s35TK.png]
[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The "Unblock" options (checkbox) is in the Properties in FILE EXPLORER, like change the Read-only Attribute. not in VS.