# Couldn't process file Properties\Resources.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have tried opening the resources file, selecting the resources, properties, and checking "Unblock". Then i reloaded the project and it didn't work. Is there any way round this?
Ps I have many pictures in my Resources but only when we added the audio files (WAV files), this error occured.

Comment: Please provide more context

Comment: Here is a discussion maybe you can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348919/couldnt-process-file-resx-due-to-its-being-in-the-internet-or-restricted-zone-o

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Couldn't process file resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348919/couldnt-process-file-resx-due-to-its-being-in-the-internet-or-restricted-zone-o)

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the solutions listed in these:

- [C# Couldn't process file xxx.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356602/c-sharp-couldnt-process-file-xxx-resx-due-to-its-being-in-the-internet-or-restr/71827845#71827845)
- [OneDrive - Visual Studio 2019 - Couldn't process file Form1.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64929131/onedrive-visual-studio-2019-couldnt-process-file-form1-resx-due-to-its-bein/71799430#71799430)

And still couldn't get it working, I ended up converting the embedded image into a .png file and made a link to that in the .resx. It's just a couple of clicks in Visual studio as I described in my original comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/71799430/15001063