# How to add a resource icon to forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and I am trying to add an icon to a form (not the application).

I have added the icon as a project resource.

While editing the form (not the application), when I use the properties tab (F4) to specify the icon, I have to specify a file (not a resource) and it updates the .Designer.cs with the line:

```
this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
```

During compile, I then receive the following error:

> Couldn't process file Form1.resx due to its being in the Internet or
>    Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file. 
>    Remove the mark of the web if you want to process these files.

If I manually edit the .Designer.cs file and specify the resource as follows it  does not produce the error:

```
this.Icon = Properties.Resources.myIcon;
```

How do I use the Properties tab of my form to specify the value Properties.Resources.myIcon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couldn't process file resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348919/couldnt-process-file-resx-due-to-its-being-in-the-internet-or-restricted-zone-o)

Comment: You probably downloaded that project from the web. You can use the PowerShell command shown in the linked question, or the [SysInternals Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams) tool to remove the Mark of the Web from the files. There's also a registry settings that prevents this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the answers to the "duplicate" question, I did not finding anything I could do except change my internet options (which I did as a test and it worked).  I didn't like that option but I started thinking about how that could have fixed the problem.

What I found to be the problem is that my source is on a server and not my local PC and the "local drive" was mapped using the IP address (//192.168.1.10/Visual Studio Projects) and not a DNS entry.  I added an entry in my hosts file

```
192.168.1.10    WindowsServer
```

I then remapped the drive using "//WindowsServer/Visual Studio Projects" instead of "//192.168.1.10/Visual Studio Projects" and that eliminated the problem.  Apparently it thinks a local IP address is still part of the internet.

I hope this information helps someone else down the road.

Comment: It's actually unrelated to the Internet itself, it just a one way to call it. This security measure is there because the file(s) come from an untrusted location.

Comment: Jimi - Can you explain why WindowsServer would be a trusted location and 192.168.1.10 is not when they are the same machine and the DNS for WindowsServer points to 192.168.1.10?  I added the DNS entry and did nothing else so what made WindowsServer trusted????

Answer (score 0):

Locate where the file in in explorer and open properties of the file that's giving you the error and check unblock then apply, then restart Visual Studio and it should be fixed

(in your case you open properties of Form1.resx)