# Can't processes Resx with msbuild commandline because its restricted

Tags: c#, ant, msbuild

I am writing an ant script (yes I know we are in 2020) to build a c# solution. This solution has many projects associate with it and for the most part i can get each project in the solution to build with the following ant task (names obfuscated due to sensitivity of the program):

```
<target name="MyProject1" description="Build MyProject1">
  <exec executable="${msbuild}">
    <arg value="MySolution.sln /t:MyProject1:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release" />
  </exec> 
</target>
```

As i mentioned this works for most of all my projects but I have one project that has a `resx` file and I get the error `Couldn't process file resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file`

I did come across this solution

[Couldn't process file resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348919/couldnt-process-file-resx-due-to-its-being-in-the-internet-or-restricted-zone-o)

Which talked about running the file through powershell so I added this to my target:

```
  <exec executable="powershell">
    <arg value="get-childitem MyResource.resx | unblock-file" />
  </exec>
```

But that did not seem to work and get the same error.

So my question would be is there another command I can run either in a batch file, as a switch to msbuild or a task in ant that will unlock the file. All the other suggestions were manual editing of the file and this has to be automated.

This file is being pulled in from a cm location that I cannot touch thus removing the lock and putting it back I cannot do. I could ask someone who does have access to change the file but that takes an act of congress (literally).

The idea behind the ant script is for any developer to be able to run it on any of our windows development machines and build the software without having to go through visual studio.

Comment: If you don't get the file from an internet-ish location over and over again you'll just have to unblock it once so there shouldn't be the need for an additional task.

Comment: The file is being pulled from a repository that I cant touch.

Comment: Looks like you have a typo: It should be `unBlock-file` not `unLock-file` and if you are dealing with exactly one file there's no need for `Get-ChildItem`, Simply do `Unblock-File MyResource.resx`

Comment: Some of the users from the question you linked to found success in adding the location to the trusted locations. Have you tried this? If you add the CM location to the trusted sites on the build server does the file get pulled down without the restriction?

Comment: @quaabaam I can try that. I wanted to avoid doing any manual entry because the idea behind the ant script is for any developer to be able to run it on any machine and build the software without having to go through visual studio

Comment: @Filburt I fixed the typo thanks and I will try your alternate suggestions. Not sure if it will change the outcome but worth a shot.

Comment: The working dir for your exec task might also be a caveat - not sure about ant but you might need to full path to your file. If possible, get log info of your exec task - it should have complained about unknown cmdlet `unlock-file` as well.

Comment: @Filburt that could be. The ant script resides in the same directory as the resx file and doesnt give an error when (actually runs successfully) but i can try to add the absolute path

Comment: Setting the trusted sites could be configured in the domain policy (if you're on a domain) It would be transparent to developers as they would get the configuration automatically from the policy. If more files were to download with the restriction then the policy could take care of it without the need to modify the script to unlock more files. That said, I'm not saying this is the way to go for you, only that it's an available option that may have some benefits worth considering.

Comment: That could work as it wouldn’t require much of a change. Just need to get IT to do it lol

Comment: So it turns out the issue was the staging area where i was running the msbuild command was a network drive. When i moved it off of a network drive and onto a local drive it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the solutions in these:

- [C# Couldn't process file xxx.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356602/c-sharp-couldnt-process-file-xxx-resx-due-to-its-being-in-the-internet-or-restr/71827845#71827845)
- [OneDrive - Visual Studio 2019 - Couldn't process file Form1.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64929131/onedrive-visual-studio-2019-couldnt-process-file-form1-resx-due-to-its-bein/71799430#71799430)

And still couldn't get it working, I ended up converting the embedded image into a .png file and made a link to that in the .resx. Visual studio does it for you with just 2 clicks as I described in my original comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/71799430/15001063